# Context-dependent translation of "appropriate"

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

The word "appropriate" has many choices or equivalents in German, such as 'passend', 'geeignet', 'angemessen', 'angebracht', 'entsprechend', and others.
But in some contexts one fits better than the other.

What are the suitable words here?

First example:

> He comes in an inappropriate time.

Second example:

> This film is inappropriate for children.

Comment: What are your suggestions?

Comment: I don’t understand the downvotes. Diese Frage ist für German SE geeignet. Warum? Weil es schwierig sein kann, anhand der Wörterbuchdefinition das angebrachte Wort für einen bestimmten Kontext zu finden.
Klingt schief? Nicht unbedingt für Nichtmuttersprachler!

Answer (score 4):

My suggestions:

First

> Er kommt zu einer unpassenden Zeit.
>
> Er kommt zur Unzeit.

Second

> Der Film ist für Kinder nicht geeignet.
>
> Der Film ist ungeeignet für Kinder.

Comment: Oder auch: ... zur ungelegenen Zeit.

Comment: Stimmt. Ungelegen ist auch sehr schön

Comment: Over four decades and this is the first time I hear 'Unzeit'. I don't think that's terribly common. 'Zu unpassender Zeit' is usually used.

Comment: It might be slightly regional. I have heard it used in every day speech, but I agree 'unpassend' is more common

Answer (score 1):

First example:

> Er kommt zur falschen Zeit. [Handwerker, während ich auf dem Klo bin]
>
> Er kommt zum falschen Zeitpunkt.

Second example (agree with Rhabarberbarbara):

> Der Film ist für Kinder nicht geeignet.
>
> Der Film ist für Kinder ungeeignet.

Answer (score 1):

First example:

> Er kommt zu einer unpassenden Zeit. (If you are currently busy)
>
> Er kommt zu einer ungeeigneten Zeit. (If the action you want to perform
>   cannot be done in this time)
>
> Er kommt zu einer unangemessenen Zeit.
>   (If it's social convention not to met you at this time)

Second example:

> Der Film ist für Kinder nicht geeignet.